# Parsing windows registry using Perl

Tags: perl, registry

I am writing up a perl script to access the values from the windows registry tree structure.

I am using the following simple script

```
use Win32::TieRegistry;
my $mykey = $Registry->{'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/HARDWARE/DESCRIPTION/System/BIOS/'};
my $mykeyval = $mykey->{'/SystemVersion'};

print " value  $mykeyval";
exit;
```

But I am unable to get the content or value

Usage: Win32API::Registry::regConstant("CONST_NAME") at C:/Dwimperl/perl/vendor/lib/Win32/TieRegistry.pm line 292

Provide me through the solution towards it. Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that's because you don't get the Administrator permissions when running your perl script, if you're on some platform such as `Win 7` or `Win Vista`.

The registry key-value of some fields, for example the ones under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, are not accessible to normal users. You could try to run your script as Administrator and watch the result.

In addition, the default delimiter of Win32::TieRegistry is `\\`. So if you would like to use `/` as delimiter, you should import the module like this:

```
use Win32::TieRegistry (Delimiter => '/');
```

Attention, even if your code is correct, there still could be no output, if your `SystemVersion` is blank, or there's no such key in your registry. So also use `Data::Dumper` to print `mykey` to check it.

Comment: Even if I am running as administrator, the result persist.

Comment: I am getting memory address as values. On modifying, I hope to get the desired output.

Comment: Right. The error message is due to the use of the wrong delimiter. And access to HKLM also requires elevated privileges, or the result is just empty.

Answer (score -1):

I have no Win-machine, so i can't try it out, but what you see with following script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Win32::TieRegistry;
my $mykey = $Registry->{'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/HARDWARE/DESCRIPTION/System/BIOS/'};

print Dumper $mykey;
```